# Is there a django equivalent to including local variables as in rails?

Tags: python, django

I'm learning Django, and I come from a rails background. As such, I'm asking a bunch of questions trying to find some grounding in django.

When you call a partial in rails, you have the option to include some local variables as part of the call:

```
 render 'folder_name/partial_name', :local_variable_name => 6 #or @variable or "a string" etc.."
```

then in the partial, the variable "local_variable_name" is available:

```
 <h1><%= local_variable_name %></h1>
```

Is there some equivalent in the django include? eg, any way to change this to accomplish this task:

```
 {% include 'folder_name/partial_name.html' %}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the [Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/templates/builtins/#include):

> You can pass additional context to the template using keyword
>   arguments:
>
> `{% include "name_snippet.html" with person="Jane" greeting="Hello" %}`
>
> If you want to only render the context with the variables provided (or
>   even no variables at all), use the only option:
>
> `{% include "name_snippet.html" with greeting="Hi" only %}`

Enjoy!